# Solving $t f''(t) + f'(t) = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

One way to solve
$$t f''(t) + f'(t) = 0$$
is to realize that $t f''(t) + f'(t) = (t f'(t))'$ to conclude that $f' = c_1/t$,
hence $f = c_2 \log t + c_3$ for some constants $c_1, c_2, c_3$.

I was stuck on this for awhile and never "saw" that  $t f''(t) + f'(t) = (t f'(t))'$.
How would I have thought of this? Other problems that use a similar trick? Are there other ways to solve this ODE? I tried other methods, but they never seemed to lead anywhere.

Comment: It is actually $tf'(t)=c_1$.

Comment: Fixed typo, thanks

Comment: But to answer your question, how I approach solving differential equations of any description is through experience. I have a term called my "mathematical toolbox" which I constantly update when I come up with a problem I have never come across before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cannot conclude that $f'=c_1t$, what you can conclude is that $(tf'(t))'= 0$ meaning that $tf'(t) = c_1$.
2. From $f'= c_1 t$, it follows that $f(t) = c_1\frac{t^2}{2} + c^2$, not what you wrote. Of course, this part is irrelevant due to point $1$.

There is another, more robust way of solving an equation like this. Taking the function $g(t) = f'(t)$, you see that $g$ satisfies the equation $$tg'(t) + g(t) = 0$$ or $$g'(t) = -\frac{g(t)}{t}$$ which you can solve using the standard method. Once you have $g$, integrate it and get $f$.

Comment: Ah, yes. Fixed typo.

Comment: Answered the second part of the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

$$
0=tf''(t)+f'(t)=\big(tf'(t)\big)',
$$
hence
$$
tf'(t)=c_1,
$$
for some constant $c_2$, and finally
$$
f'(t)=\frac{c_1}{t} \quad\text{or}\quad f(t)=c_1\log |t|+c_2,
$$
for another constant $c_2$.

Comment: Where did $1/t^2$ come from? It should be a logarithm.

Comment: -1 until you fix the presumable typo.

Answer (score 0):

On an interval where $f'$ doesn't vanish we have
$$\frac{f''}{f'}=-\frac1t$$
and we integrate we find
$$f'(t)=\frac{c_1}t$$
hence
$$f(t)=c_1\ln |t|+c_2,\quad \; c_1,c_2\in\Bbb R$$

Comment: $$\int\frac{f''(t)}{f'(t)}dt=\int\frac{(f')'(t)}{f'(t)}dt=\ln|f'(t)|+c=-\ln|t|+c$$
and apply the exponential function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's useful to learn to recognize Leibnitz rule: $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$. In your case

$$tf''+f'=0\Rightarrow (tf')'=0\Rightarrow tf'=c_1$$
then
$$f'=c_1/t\Rightarrow f = c_1 \ln |t| +c_2.$$ This is not a trick, this is common technique, especially while learning.

Another approach would be to multiply the equation by $t$ and then make the change of variables $t=e^z$, $y(z) = f(e^z)$ (for $t>0$; for $t<0$ the reasoning is the same). When you write the differential equation on $y$, you obtain $$y'(z) = f'(e^z)e^z,\quad y''(z) = f''(e^z)e^{2z}+f'(e^z)e^z,$$
therefore
$$y''(z)=0,$$
which is easy to solve: $y(z) = c_1z+c_2$, and when you return to $f(t)$, you obtain $$f(t) = c_2+c_1 \ln |t|.$$
This is a less common technique, sometimes called "Eulerian change of variables", but it can come out surprisingly useful.

Comment: Very nice, I like the change of variables.